# jqtransform onclick events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form using the jqtransform jQuery plugin that gives forms an aesthetic makeover. However, I can't get my onclick events to fire.

I have a form setup similar to this:

```
<select name="person">
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="2">No</option>
<option class="maybe" value="0">Maybe</option>
</select>
```

I also have a hidden div container which expands the form:

```
<div class="expander" style="display:none;">
More info <input type="text" name="moreinfo" />
</div>
```

Then the final piece of the puzzle:

```
<script>
$(".maybe").click(function () {
$(".expander").show("slow");
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the change event instead of click.

http://api.jquery.com/change

here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dwick/Sh4PA/

Comment: Thanks again David. Your example works with jqtransform disabled, but my question is trying to find out why my events wont fire with jqtransform switched on.

Comment: the issue is with the plugin you're using.  it's recreating the fields as styled elements and not taking event handlers with it.  imo, more trouble than its worth.

Comment: i fixed the issue with jqtransform, you can take the source from the fiddle in the answer; which should be doing what you asked for.  however, i suspect you're just going to keep running into more issues with this plugin... and it looks like a dead project.  i wouldn't advise using it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help David, but I'm using the plugin across my application and I can't just ditch it now. I'd love to figure out why this isn't working - I've been researching similar issues for about a week but nothing I've tried works for my problem. I know this issue is deep rooted within the plugin but I think this is out of my scope.

Comment: here's a guy trying to struggle with this plugin... http://blog.divdesigns.com/2010/02/dynamic-forms-with-jqtransform/

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty workaround, but works for me...

change the type of your input field to reset, then add an onclick event handler

```
<input type='reset' value='submit' onclick='$(#myFormId).submit()' />
```